# Pstate (underclock) on single core hyperthreaded cpu

Tags: cpu, hyper-threading, underclock, cpufreq

In Ubuntu, I can underclock the CPU using the CPU freq applet. My netbook is a Intel atom n270, basically single core with 2 "virtual cores" due to hyperthreading. I can underclock one of these virtual cores while having the other stay at 1.6 GHz. Which frequency is my CPU actually running at?

Comment: Even if you were able to, wouldn't it just be pretending to run slower?

Comment: Yea, judging by how hyperthreading works http://arstechnica.com/features/2002/10/hyperthreading/ , it seems the applet you used in Ubuntu didn't actually detect that it's trying to downclock virtual cores. Both your virtual cores run from a single physical core, so your CPU still run at the exact same speed.